# Any way to Disable or Prevent Status bar and Navigation bar from popping up Permanently when sliding in within app?

Tags: navigationbar, uistatusbar

My 2d unity Android app is running full screen. However when I swipe from top or bottom/right corners in, the status and navigation bars always pop up within my app. Sliding a second time from top will bring up the shortcut menu with wifi, location etc. Is there anyway to disable or hide this them PERMANENTLY within unity. If no, is there any other ways. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96IlZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNRDY.png)

Screen pinning is a good option but it takes too many steps to activate it. I hope the hiding can be done within my app.

Within unity, iave tried a lot of different scripts such as blocking off touches on top or bottom 10% of screen in unity, java plugin gives me errors. Sorry im new im programming. Is it impossible to modify this as its native android behavior? Any workaround or alternative method.